# How to make tabs with pure HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, tabs

I'm trying to do Tabs with pure HTML/CSS, and it works nice in all major browsers. Except IE, both 7 and 8.

If I don't add `display: table` to the *ul*, the content is not on a new line in every browser. However, IE doesn't display it in a new line even after I add that. What can I do about that? Is there a better way to make tabs in pure HTML/CSS?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          ul.tabs {
              display: table;
              list-style-type: none;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
          }

          ul.tabs>li {
              float: left;
              padding: 10px;
              background-color: lightgray;
          }

          ul.tabs>li:hover {
              background-color: yellow;
          }

          ul.tabs>li.selected {
              background-color: orange;
          }

          div.content {
              border: 1px solid black;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="selected">One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="content">
            This should really appear on a new line.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the floated `<li>` elements your `<ul>` element is zero height.

Try adding `ul { overflow: auto; }` and `div.content { clear: both; }` to your CSS

Comment: This does work if I have only one column, as in the example, but I have a two column layout (sorry for not including this in the question). If I use "clear: left", it works, but the tabs are at the same height as the second column then.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this approach which works well. It uses an inline list: http://nontroppo.org/test/tab1.html

UPDATE: Above is outdated. If I were to answer the question now I would suggest using the CSS target pseudo-class method outlined here: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target. There are other methods like using (hidden) radio buttons in combo with the checked pseudo-class but using target seems the cleanest.

Comment: hi, this is not a tabbed because it loads separate page for each tab, it will make site slow

Comment: Excuse me? The OP wasn't explicit about whether it needed to load in the same page. Take a look at the users code example - that was what they wanted. I also disagree it would make the site slow given you're only loading the content needed for the tab you're viewing. What if you never look at tab 2 and 3? You've loaded them for nothing. It really depends on the implemention of the tabs i.e. are they for primary navigation (use separate pages) or supplementary content (have all tab content in same page).

Comment: ... further to above If I were to answer the question now I would suggest using the CSS target pseudo-class method outlined here: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target - this question was asked over 2 years ago!

Comment: @ShaneGarelja The CSS target pseudo class is a great approach. You should probably add that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I always just "float" the `li` elements:

```css
ul.tabs{list-style: none;}
ul.tabs li{float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CE9KK/1/) (jsfiddle) work for you?

Changes made:

1. Removed `display: table;` from ul.tabs
2. Removed `float:left` from ul.tabs li's
3. Added `display:inline-block` to ul.tabs li's